# Necessary to state power when using 'billion' in UK publication?

Tags: publications, journals, united-kingdom, grammar

In British English, a billion traditionally had a different meaning to in American English (10^12). In modern writing the American convention has pretty much taken over. Is it therefore okay in a British publication to write 'billion' and assume the meaning will be unambiguous (e.g. 'approximately one billion years old'), or should the figure (or SI equivalent e.g. G, Ga) always be stated still to ensure clarity?

Comment: I don't think million ever meant 10^9, it's been always 10^6. The differences were over billion, and whether billion meant a million millions, i.e. 10^12, or a thousand million, 10^9.

Comment: When in doubt, aim for unambiguous language -- that's what the SI equivalents are there for, after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be unusual to me to see million or billion used in academic scientific contexts, except for a few cases where there would be absolutely no ambiguity (number of people on earth or age of rocks, for example, would only fall under the American/modern usage of billion), and even in those contexts, only for loose descriptions (versus reporting of data). (I did a brief Google Scholar search for both million and billion; although there were many many results, most seemed to be referencing either *authors surnamed* Million or Billion, or the use of the terms in these loose forms or in the context of geology, as in "three billion year-old rocks)

I can't think of a circumstance where scientific notation or use of SI prefixes would be a problem when writing for an scientific academic audience. If writing for a lay audience or outside the hard sciences, it might make more sense to use million/billion: most respectable outlets will either have a style guide or refer to another established style guide for proper procedure. It seems like the [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/journalism/article/art20130702112133541) and [University of Cambridge](https://www.cam.ac.uk/brand-resources/guidelines/editorial-style-guide) embrace the 10^9 billion and do not caution specifically against its use, only noting the previous definition. Certainly in no context should you use billion to mean 10^12.

Comment: Thanks. I'm reproducing a figure that uses it so it got me curious about this in a more general context. I'll edit the figure.

Comment: Your first sentence implies that there is sometimes ambiguity about whether billion means 10^9 or 10^12. There is no ambiguity! You should trust someone who knows, not try to guess by looking on the web. (I suppose my comments are merely "on the web" too, but you know what I mean.) Other points: Are you saying that the BBC and Cambridge webpages don't caution specifically against the use of the word "billion"? Of course they don't - it is a common word. And your view that "million" and "billion" should not normally be used in academic writing might be reasonable, but it is a separate issue.

Comment: So if I should not use "billion", how would I say `The bacteria population grew to x.` if x=3*10^12? `3 Terabacteria`?

Comment: I agree with problemofficer. A country's population or a number of genetic variants might also be something like 3.27 million. So I don't think that Bryan Krause's view about that is reasonable, on second thoughts.

Comment: @problemofficer If you are talking about a bacterial population, you are probably talking about a volume, and often using Colony Forming Units for the actual count. "The bacterial population grew to 3*10^12 CFUs/L."

Comment: @user1310503 My first sentence said that it's unusual to spell out those words in scientific contexts - I said nothing about the ambiguity of millions or billions. The whole point of the OP is that *up until several decades ago, 'billion' had a different meaning in British English versus American English*. It might seem obvious what the meaning of billion is now, but by avoiding the use of the word, potential readers in 100 years won't have to recall whether this paper was published before or after the switch of the meaning "billion."

Comment: @BryanKrause: That was only an example of course. What if there is no unit and I just want to express a number? Are you saying: "Always just use a product of a coefficient and a power of ten."?

Comment: @problemofficer I'm saying it's completely unambiguous if you do so. I mentioned "loose contexts" in my first paragraph: if you are using it in that context and the meaning is clear, go ahead and use the billion notation. If you're talking about populations of people, it will be pretty clear you don't ever mean 10^12.

Comment: *I can't think of a circumstance where scientific notation or use of SI prefixes would be a problem when writing for an academic audience.* Really? What about articles in fields outside the hard sciences?  Say, a history paper: "The 1871 Treaty of Frankfurt obligated France to pay 5 gigafrancs to Prussia"?

Comment: @NateEldredge Edited. I meant to carry over the "scientific contexts" from the first sentence in my answer through the rest of the text. The OP didn't specify a context, but their profile suggests physics so I answered primarily with that in mind. Also if it were the British obligating the French to pay 5 billion francs to Prussia, the Prussians would be very happy indeed that it were 1871 and not 1990 - it seems like in a historical context like that it might be especially important to clarify.

Comment: @BryanKrause _My first sentence said that it's unusual to spell out those words in scientific contexts - I said nothing about the ambiguity of millions or billions._ It did say it's unusual to spell out the words, but it also implied that "billion" is ambiguous. I quote: _except for a few cases where there would be absolutely no ambiguity_. If you meant some other type of ambiguity then I think the sentence needs editing. Your point about readers 100 years in the future might be good, but the question and your answer don't mention that issue.

Answer (score 4):

The American meaning has completely taken over in the UK, and this has been true for at least 25 years. If you don't believe me then look at British newspapers from 1990. So it is most definitely OK in a British publication to assume that billion means 10^9.

From a 2011 [BBC News article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-15478580) article:

> In 1974, Harold Wilson pledged that the British government would adopt the "short scale" naming system used in the US to avoid ambiguity. As a result, the value of billion is now generally understood to mean a thousand millions. Nonetheless this is still a bone of contention for many, and the older sense "a million millions" is still common.

The last sentence is wrong. The older sense has not been common for several decades, though I suppose it might be used privately by eccentric people.